# Delphi Live binding, error converting text to TStrings field

Tags: delphi, livebindings

Delphi 10.4

I have an issue bidirectional Tstrings binding. I have a simple app with 2 controls and a bind source. I am trying to bind bidirectionally a TStrings property of an object to to a TMemo control. I am using a TPrototypeBindSource with a TObjectBindSourceAdapter as the bind source adapter.

I have the lines property on the TPrototypeBindSource set to a ftTStrings fieldtype

[image]

TFoo is defined as;

```
  TFoo = class  (TObject)
  private
    Fname: string;
    flines: TStrings;
  published
    constructor Create;
    destructor destroy; override;
    property name: string read Fname write Fname;
    property lines: Tstrings read Flines write Flines;
  end;
```

The Adapter is set with the on create event

```
procedure TForm1.PrototypeBindSource1CreateAdapter(Sender: TObject; var ABindSourceAdapter: TBindSourceAdapter);
begin
  ABindSourceAdapter := TObjectBindSourceAdapter<TFoo>.Create(Self, GetFoo, False);
end;
```

Using live bindings I have the

PrototypeBindSource name fielddef <---> edit text field.
PrototypeBindSource lines fielddef <---> memo text field.

[image]

All is good when you are reading or updating the name <-> edit control and when setting the memo text field. It recognises the lines field in the TPrototypeBindSource as being a TStrings.

However, when I change the text in the memo and go to post it back to the TPrototypeBindSource I get this exception

EBindConverterError : unable to cast or find converters between types string and TObject

There is a TStrings to string  and string to TStrings converters registered. But there seems a disconnect between the TString in the object and the adapter as it cannot seem to see its type.

Have I missed something or is the RTL got issues?

EDIT:

Thanks, I missed that setter. Even with it fixed the issue remains...

```
  TFoo = class  (TObject)
    ...
    procedure SetLines(const aValue: TStrings);
    ...
  end;

procedure TFoo.SetLines(const Value: TStrings);
begin
  Flines.Assign(Value);
end;
```

The converters don't go through the setter they use the TStrings text property

```
system.bindings.outputs

class procedure TConverterUtils.StringToStrings(const I: TValue; var O: TValue);
var
  oOut: TStrings;
begin
  oOut := TStrings(O.AsObject);                                            
  if oOut <> nil then
  begin
    if I.IsEmpty then
      oOut.Text := ''
    else
      oOut.Text := I.AsString;
  end;
end;
```

Tracing through the binding code, the converters get called in here

```
procedure TBindingOutput.SetValue(AExpression: TObject; const ValueFunc: TBindOutValueFunc);

begin
...
  if AllowConverter then
    CanConvert := ValueConverter.CanConvert(LFinalOutVal.TypeInfo, LocationRec.Location.GetType);
...
end
```

Which calls;

```
function TValueRefConverter.CanConvert(AFrom, ATo: PTypeInfo): Boolean;
begin
  Result := GetConverter(AFrom, ATo, False) <> nil;
end;
```

When going from the TStrings property to the Text prop on the TMemo, the TypeInfo for the AFrom shows as a TStringlist, but when it is going back the other way the ATo PTypeInfo shows TObject not TStringList.

As the converters are registered for TStrings it cannot find the appropriate converter.

I got lost trying to work out where the info is stored.

Comment: Is your code for creating binder adapter correct? Looking at `LiveBindings\AdapterbindSource` sample that ships with Delphi it seems you have defined your adapter binder code wrong. Souldn't it be `ABindSourceAdapter := TObjectBindSourceAdapter<TStrings>.Create(Self, GetFoo, False);` instead. You need to tel the binder adapter with what type of data it will operate. But in your code you are passing the class of your custom object instead. That is probably why you get `TObject` type instead of `TStrings` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at `TMemo` source code you will see that `Lines` property is defined differently as your `Lines` property

```
property Lines: TStrings read FLines write SetLines;
```

As you can see `TMemo` lines property relies on the use of writer method instead of directly writing to FLines field as you do in your code.

In that `SetLines` writer method [TStrings.Assign](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Assign) method is called.

```
procedure TCustomMemo.SetLines(Value: TStrings);
begin
  FLines.Assign(Value);
end;
```

Using this method a copy of the strings from source is made to its destination.

The way how you code is set you simply assign the reference of the source `TLines` object to your `flines` field making both objects to share same `TLines` object. This is extremely dangerous because if the source object gets destroyed your objects ends up referencing to a no longer existing data which could lead to a whole lot of problems.

Fix your `Lines` property to match the design from TMemo and this should solve your problem

Comment: Fixed the setter, thanks. Issue remains, see updated question. Cheers